# WebStorm Reformat Code (Prettier) does format the same as `prettier --write .`

Tags: typescript, webstorm, prettier

I am working on a code base (TS) where `prettier --write .` should be run before each commit.

However I am using `Reformat Code` action in WebStorm to run Prettier which is more convenient. Using this action the code is also reformatted, for example adding a missing `;` at the end of a line. But I found out that for example empty lines are not removed.
But when I run `prettier --write .` those empty lines are removed.

I was under the assumption that `Reformat Code` in WebStorm with Prettier is the equivalent as running `prettier --write` on that file.

How can I have the same behavior so that I can commit without running Prettier manually?

This is the only settings I could find in the code base:

```
 "prettier": {
    "singleQuote": true,
    "arrowParens": "avoid"
  },
```

In WebStorm I could not find any setting which describes the config it is using:

[image]

Comment: Are you using same config files for both actions? re-formatting won't remove empty lines (if not configured explicitly). If you run re-format action again, Webstorm will prompt you to know if you would like to remove unnecessary empty lines.

Comment: regarding the code base: there are only 2 things in the `package.json` prettier object defined: `singleQuote` and `arrowParens`. In terms of Webstorm... there is nothing where I can set a config... again I assume that its using the same as from the code base, in this case the setting in the `package.json`

Comment: In Webstorm settings/preferences, you can search and configure prettier config.

Comment: there is no setting which points to any config files or where I can add prettier specific settings

Comment: There is one under Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript -> **Prettier**

Comment: sorry my bad I added the wrong image, I can only set the package and 'run for files'

Comment: Have you tried checking the `On 'Reformat Code' action` under prettier? Webstorm by default doesn't use prettier to format. When you check this box, it will start using prettier and use the same formatting config as prettier

Comment: that was the issue... thanks...